# Was Matthew 28:19 changed? The greatest commission

Tags: gospel-of-matthew, textual-criticism

The original texts are "baptize them in my name" or "in Jesus name". The texts had been changed to "in the name of the Father, the son and holy Spirit".

If it's true that the verse was changed, why hasn't there been a action to change it to its original text.

Comment: Which texts say that? Are you confusing it with [1 John 5:7-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_Johanneum) which almost certainly has an addition mentioning "the father, word, and holy spirit"?

Comment: Or if you are asking about Matt 28:19, see also [Was the text of Matthew 28:19 changed?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/12794/2757)

Comment: @curiousdanni The apostles didn't follow Mathew 28:19, they baptized all in his name. ( Jesus Christ ).

Comment: If there was some conspiracy to change this verse In Matthew, why wouldn't they also change the verses in Acts to match? That the disciples didn't follow this instruction literally doesn't give us any reason to doubt the text of the verse.

Comment: That verse is the greatest commission.

Comment: @curiousdannii Acts 10:48 so he ordered them to be baptized in the name of Jesus Christ.

Comment: +AshJeyaraj 'In the name of Jesus' is in contrast to the baptism of mere repentance of John (Acts 18:25), as opposed to "into Christ." Gal 3:27 It was a way of speaking of New Testament baptism as opposed to what is technically the Old Testament practice practiced by St. John. We see from the earliest extant Christian catechism, which is evidently very primitive, that it also says: "And concerning b., baptize this way: Having first said all these things, baptize into the name of Father and Son and Holy Spirit... ... if you have not either, pour out water thrice upon the head into the name [^]"

Answer (score 1):

The original text of Matthew 28:19 said ". . . in the name of the Father, and of the Son, and of the Holy Spirit;" (Phonetically in Greek: ". . . eis to onoma tou Patros, kai tou Huiou, kai tou Hagiou Pnuematos;")

If you'd like to see for yourself, the Interlinear Bible displays the original Greek alongside each word's literal English translation. Matthew 28:19 is here: http://biblehub.com/interlinear/matthew/28-19.htm

Comment: The apostles didn't follow Mathew 28:19, they baptized all by the name of Jesus Christ.

Comment: So the original text must be , by his name.